# Is Draupadi the incarnation of Devi Kali as per Devi Bhagwatam?

Tags: mahabharata, avatars, devi-bhagavata-purana, draupadi

Someone said that as per Devi Bhagwatam Puranam, Devi Drauapdi was the incarnation of Devi Kali. Is that true.?

Comment: No, Sachi (Indra's wife) -Adi parva/Sambhava parva

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What were the previous births of the characters of Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7039/what-were-the-previous-births-of-the-characters-of-mahabharata) and [Is Draupadi a goddess?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10156/is-draupadi-a-goddess)

Comment: In Devi Bhagwatam, she is considered as part incarnation of Laxmi or Chhaya Sita - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57329.html ...one answer under "What were the previous births of the characters of Mahabharata?" is from Devi Bhagavata...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Draupadi a goddess?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10156/is-draupadi-a-goddess)

Comment: I checked it but I also need proof for Drauapdi being Devi Kali in Devi Bhagwatam

Comment: Dude, i have changed the upa puran as its still not clear which one is the ipa puran as for some scholars Vishnu/Krishna Bhagwatam is the upa puran and Devi Bhagwatam is the MahaPurana and for some its vice-versa. So, there is still some [conflicts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/can-the-devi-bhagavatam-and-srimad-bhagavatam-co-exist/50445#50445) going on regarding this matter. So, its better to only use purana or just using their name as it is. Period. ..

Comment: According to south india, Draupadi is worship their as Goddess Kali (Draupadi Amma) as their kuldevi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Story of Draupadī as per Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa

According to Devī Bhāgavata, Draupadī was a partial incarnation (Aṃśa) of svarga Lakṣmī - Śacī (शची).

[Chapter 22](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57421.html), Book 4, Devī Bhāgavatapurāṇa

> द्रुपदो वरुणस्यांशो **द्रौपदी च रमांशजा** ॥ ३९
>
> Draupadī, was part incarnate of Lakṣmī.

##### But, which Lakṣmī is it?

Is she god Viṣṇu's wife?

#### Not exactly, but partially.

This is answered in [Chapter 16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57329.html), Book 9, Devī Bhāgavatapurāṇa

> कुशध्वजस्य पत्‍नी च देवी मालावती सती ।
> सा सुषाव च कालेन **कमलांशां** सुतां सतीम् ॥ ३ ॥
>
> [श्रीरामाग्नी ऊचतुः](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AF/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%AC)
>
> त्वं गच्छ तपसे देवि पुष्करं च सुपुण्यदम् । कृत्वा तपस्या तत्रैव
> स्वर्गलक्ष्मीर्भविष्यसि ॥ ४९ ॥ सा च तद्वचनं श्रुत्वा प्रतप्य पुष्करे
> तपः । **दिव्यं त्रिलक्षवर्षं च स्वर्गलक्ष्मीर्बभूव ह ॥ ५० ॥ सा च कालेन
> तपसा यज्ञकुण्डसमुद्‍भवा । कामिनी पाण्डवानां च द्रौपदी द्रुपदात्मजा ॥**
> ५१ ॥ कृते युगे वेदवती कुशध्वजसुता शुभा । त्रेतायां रामपत्‍नी च सीतेति
> जनकात्मजा ॥ ५२ ॥ तच्छाया द्रौपदी देवी द्वापरे द्रुपदात्मजा । त्रिहायणी
> च सा प्रोक्ता विद्यमाना युगत्रये ॥ ५३ ॥
>
> > 3. After a long time, the chaste wife (of Kuśadhvaja named Mālāvatī), delivered one daughter **(Vedavatī), born of the parts of Kamalā.**
>
> ...
>
> > 49. to 53. Agni and Rāmacandra both of them then said to Chāyā Sītā :-- “O
> >     Devī! Go to Puṣkara and practise tapasyā there; that place is the
> >     giver of religious merits and **then you will be the Svarga Lakṣmī
> >     (Lakṣmī of Heaven)**.” Hearing this, the **Chāyā Sītā went and practised
> >     tapasyā for the three divine lakh years and became Mahā Lakṣmī. This
> >     Svarga Lakṣmī appeared at one time from the sacrificial Kuṇḍa (pit).
> >     She was known as the daughter of Drupada and became the wife of the
> >     five Pāṇḍavas.** She was Veda Vatī, the daughter of Kuśadhvaja in the
> >     Satya Yuga; Sītā, the wife of Rāma and the daughter of Janaka in Tretā
> >     Yuga; and Draupadī, the daughter of Drupada, in the Dvāpara Yuga. As
> >     she existed in the Satya, Tretā, and Dvāpara Yugas, the Three Yugas,
> >     hence She is Trihāyanī.
>
> English Translation by Swami Vijñanananda

So, as per Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa, Draupadī was the incarnation of svarga Lakṣmī, Śacī (शची) - the wife of Indra-deva, who in turn was in her previous life, the manifestation of Chāyā Sītā (छाया सीता), who in turn was part of part of Kamalā (Lakṣmī).

---

### Therefore, as per Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa, Draupadī was NOT an incarnation of goddess Kālī, but a part of partial incarnation of goddess Kamalā (Lakṣmī).

---

### `So which scripture say Draupadī was incarnation of Devi Kālī?`

Skanda Purāṇa do say that Draupadī and the Pāṇḍavas were manifestations of Pārvatī (Umā), i.e. Kālī, and Rudra (Śiva) respectively.

[Chapter 49,](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423787.html) Section 1 - Pūrvārdha,  Book 4 - Kāśī-khaṇḍa, Skanda Purāṇa

> उमापि च जगद्धात्री द्रुपदस्य महीभुजः ।
>  यजतो वह्निकुंडाच्च
> प्रादुश्चक्रेति सुंदरी ॥ ४ ॥
>  पंचापि पांडुतनयाः
> साक्षाद्रुद्रवपुर्धराः ।
>  अवतेरुरिह स्वर्गाद्दुष्टसंहारकारकाः ॥ ५
> ॥
>
> > 4. **Umā, the mother of the universe, also manifested herself as a very beautiful lady (Draupadī) from the sacrificial fire pit of king Drupada.**
>
> > 5. **The five sons of Pāṇḍu (Pāṇḍavas) were the embodied forms of Rudra taking incarnations on the earth from heaven for the destruction of the
> >    wicked ones.**
>
> English Translation by G. V. Tagare

---

##### Unverifiable information

Also, some [social media handles](https://m.facebook.com/Chinnamastasaranam/posts/2668454956730304?comment_id=2668504856725314&_se_imp=0UOvq9MMNIKtl8S3K) are claiming that Draupadī indeed was an incarnation of MahāKālī basis a text called Draupadī Kalpa from the (now lost) Rudrāyamala Tantra, as follows:-

> पांचालीं पंचवीरस्य रमणीं कामरूपिणीं।
> द्रौपदीं अग्निजां वंदे कुरूवंशविनाशिनीं ।।
>
> > Draupadī is the Avatar of Goddess Durgā.

> > "In Rudrāyamala tantra's Draupadī Kalpa, Devī Pāñchālī is described as devī Mahākālī's incarnation."

And, the Pāṇḍavas are told as manifestation of the Pañchabrahmās manifestations of god Śiva :- Īśāna, Tatpuruṣa, Aghora, Vāmadeva and Sadyojāta

> ईशानं धर्मदेवोक्तं भीमं तत्पुरुषं तथा ।
> अघोरमर्जुनं चैव नकुलं वामदेवकम् ॥
> सहादेवं तु सद्यानां पांडवं भावयेत् सदा ॥

---

**But, I can't verify or trace any of this information.**

Answer (score 1):

The 5 primary manifestations of Prakriti (Adi-Shakti) are Goddesses Radha, Durga, Lakshmi, Saraswati and Savitri. All women in this universe have emerged from a part of Prakriti [Ref: Devi Bhagavatam 9.1.1, 9.1.96-143].

When there is a birth of a girl child in the house, don't we say Goddess Lakshmi has taken birth in our family?

Coming to Draupadi's birth.

Maharishi Vyasa said that a chaste daughter of an illustrious Rishi had performed tapasya (austerities) to appease God Shiva. When God Shiva had appeared before her, she had asked for a husband. He said she would have 5 husbands in her next life since she had repeated her request 5 times. Draupadi was thus born in Drupada’s home to fulfil God Shiva’s earlier boon [Ref: Mahabharata 1.171 and also 1.199 translated by KMG].

So, in her previous birth she was a Rishi's daughter and of course, she is a part of Goddess Lakshmi too.